# ¿Cómo sucedió la bárbara evolución del significado la palabra "bárbaro"?

Tags: significado, historia, adjetivos

¿Cómo pasó que esta palabra de origen griego de carácter peyorativo pasó a convertirse en una exclamación de algo "excelente", "magnífico" o "extraordinario"?

Fuentes

> [wiki, el que balbucea](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A1rbaro)
>
> > *Bárbaro es un exónimo peyorativo que procede del griego (βάρβαρος)1​ y su traducción literal es "**el que balbucea**".*
>
> [Rae](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=b%C3%A1rbaro)
>
> > *7. adj. Excelente, llamativo, magnífico. El orador estuvo bárbaro.*

Comment: @ukemi yo redactando una respuesta y resulta que ya había elaborado una para esa otra pregunta, así estaba yo teniendo un _dejabugo_. Curioso que el razonamiento para esta pregunta no se parezca al elaborado para la otra...

Answer (score 1):

Sí que es cierto que esta palabra ha sufrido una evolución *bárbara*. Vamos paso a paso viendo los significados que ha tenido a lo largo de la historia.

En un principio parece que se usó para designar a los extranjeros. Dice Covarrubias (1611) que viene del griego, del sonido *barbar*, por la mala pronunciación de los extranjeros. Del griego pasó al latín, que llamaban bárbaros y los extranjeros (salvo a los griegos). De ahí que se pasara a denominar *bárbaro* a aquellos que hablan con tosquedad y grosería, y de ahí a los que son ignorantes e iletrados, a los de malas costumbres, a los que no atienden a razones y viven sin ella y, por último, a los despiadados y crueles. Se quedó a gusto Covarrubias.

Un siglo más tarde, el *Diccionario de autoridades* recoge estas acepciones de inculto, grosero, rudo, cruel, despiadado... pero añade una nueva: "se toma algunas veces por temerario, destemplado y precipitado, e inconsiderablemente violento". En 1803 esta acepción decía simplemente "arrojado, temerario".

Veamos qué frases nos encontrábamos por entonces con esta palabra:

> *¿Quién me consuela? Apenas puedo respirar. ¡Ah, bárbaro tormento! ¡Qué penas no pasarás, Lisandro mío, al oír tan funesta nueva!*
>
> Ignacio García Malo, "Voz de la naturaleza. Memorias o anécdotas curiosas e instructivas", 1787-1803 (España).

Aquí se usa la palabra *bárbaro* como "fiero, cruel", pero podría ser fácilmente interpretada como "grande", dado que *tormento* ya lleva una carga negativa de dolor. ¿Qué nos impediría usar *bárbaro* como "grande" con otras palabras de carga positiva? El diccionario en todo caso se mantuvo así durante mucho tiempo, aunque poco a poco vamos encontrando ejemplos de uso de *bárbaro* que demuestran ese doble sentido que se va apoderando de la palabra:

> *¡Vaya un señor apetito que me está entrando! Es un apetito famélico, como el que uno tiene cuando es muchacho, y vuelve de la escuela... ¡Si me comería medio carnero! [...] ¡Pero qué apetito tan bárbaro!*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Torquemada y San Pedro", 1895 (España).

Un ejemplo aún más claro del uso de *bárbaro* como "digno de gente bárbara", pero que se puede interpretar fácilmente como "enorme, desmedido". A esto ayudó el uso de expresiones como "yo lo pasé bárbaro" (1956), con claras connotaciones positivas, e igualmente "un trabajo bárbaro" (1960). Esto culminó con la entrada en 1984 en el diccionario de dos nuevas acepciones de la palabra:

> 7. Excelente, llamativo, magnífico. || **¡qué bárbaro!** exclam. que indica asombro, admiración, extrañeza.

Comment: precisamente me pareció que la connotación y carga positiva debió haber nacido de la admiración del poder y la fuerza. que vienen muy relacionados la rudeza, ferocidad y violencia. algo que españa sufrió mucho durante la era medieval.